# Why does currying foldr with @ produce an operator domain error?

Tags: sml

So I'm writing a flatten fn, and I got it to this:

```
fun flatten ls = List.foldr op @ [] ls
```

And I realized that naming the variable `ls` should be unnecessary, instead I could probably just paritally apply `foldr`. But this breaks:

```
val flatten = List.foldr op @ []
```

Whats making it mess up? I seems like the *typ* would have to be inferred for both the `fun` declaration and for the partially applied `foldr`.

A similar sum function works, which makes me wonder why `@` is particularly not working:

```
val sum = List.foldr op + 0
```

---

**Edit:** the error I'm getting:

```
- val flatten = List.foldr op @ [];

stdIn:1.6-2.13 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
   value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
val flatten = fn : ?.X1 list list -> ?.X1 list

- flatten [[1], [1]];

stdIn:3.1-3.19 Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]
  operator domain: ?.X1 list list
  operand:         int list list
  in expression:
    flatten ((1 :: nil) :: (1 :: nil) :: nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear on what error exactly you are referring to. You mention in the headline that you are getting an "operator domain error", however you code just produces a "value restriction" warning. There is a big difference.

Value restriction is one of the more complex things to get your head around, but in essence it is there to preserve type safety when having references in the language.

The MLton wiki has a great article on [value restriction](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction), which covers Why the value restriction exists, unnecessarily rejected programs, alternatives to the value restriction and how to work with the value restriction.

Comment: edited. the statement itself doesn't break, but i can't use it!

Comment: finally had time to read through the article, and it seems like the reason the val statement doesnt work is that the `nil` list can't be typed unless the *typ* of the passed in `ls` is known. Do I have that right?

Comment: Well it is both the empty list and the append function, which are polymorphic. So both makes the final statement a polymorphic function.

Answer (score 1):

AJ,
Jesper's article both explains the warning you see, and is insightful, but for a more practical solution to your problem, you might want to try this:

```
val flatten = foldr op @ ([]:int list);
```

I believe that should solve your problem.

**EDIT**: I chose `int list` as the explicit type because I observed the nature of your warning message, and inferred from there, `int list` was what you needed. [=

**Note**: Above solution destroys polymorphism and restricts input to the type chosen.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! it makes absolutely no sense to ruin polymorphism imo so i'll just stick with the fun syntax

Comment: I agree... using `fun` seems like the most sensible solution, and definitely avoids unnecessary headaches.

Comment: In this case yes. But there are plenty of other cases where you may use a val-binding as you originally tried, instead of creating a function for it.